# Установка libpqxx для visual studio 2022

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, visual-studio, libpq

Начал недавно работать с visual studio 2022. Всегда работал в QT Creator. Хочу добавить библиотеку для работы с Postgresql. Почитал и нашел lippqxx. Скачал, разархивировал и сделал cmake в build.После этого открыл в visualk studio проект libpqxx.sln. Собрал ALL_BUILDS и INSTALL по стандарту 20. В своем проекте уже добавил папки libpqxx/include и libpqxx/build/lib
По проект не собирается, думаю, что я с чем-то напортачил или что-то еще не добавил. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, заранее спасибо
Вот вывод vs:

```
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "int __cdecl pqxx::internal::check_pqxx_version_7_7(void)" (?check_pqxx_version_7_7@internal@pqxx@@YAHXZ) в функции "void __cdecl pqxx::check_version(void)" (?check_version@pqxx@@YAXXZ).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class pqxx::const_result_iterator __cdecl pqxx::result::begin(void)const " (?begin@result@pqxx@@QEBA?AVconst_result_iterator@2@XZ) в функции main.
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: int __cdecl pqxx::result::size(void)const " (?size@result@pqxx@@QEBAHXZ) в функции "public: class pqxx::const_result_iterator __cdecl pqxx::result::end(void)const " (?end@result@pqxx@@QEBA?AVconst_result_iterator@2@XZ).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: int __cdecl pqxx::result::columns(void)const " (?columns@result@pqxx@@QEBAHXZ) в функции "private: __cdecl pqxx::const_result_iterator::const_result_iterator(class pqxx::result const *,int)" (??0const_result_iterator@pqxx@@AEAA@PEBVresult@1@H@Z).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl pqxx::internal::demangle_type_name(char const * const)" (?demangle_type_name@internal@pqxx@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEBD@Z) в функции "??__E?$type_name@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@pqxx@@YAXXZ" (??__E?$type_name@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@pqxx@@YAXXZ).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __cdecl pqxx::connection::close(void)" (?close@connection@pqxx@@QEAAXXZ) в функции "public: __cdecl pqxx::connection::~connection(void)" (??1connection@pqxx@@QEAA@XZ).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "private: void __cdecl pqxx::connection::init(char const * const)" (?init@connection@pqxx@@AEAAXQEBD@Z) в функции "public: __cdecl pqxx::connection::connection(char const * const)" (??0connection@pqxx@@QEAA@QEBD@Z).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: char const * __cdecl pqxx::field::c_str(void)const & " (?c_str@field@pqxx@@QEGBAPEBDXZ) в функции main.
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class pqxx::field __cdecl pqxx::row::operator[](int)const " (??Arow@pqxx@@QEBA?AVfield@1@H@Z) в функции main.
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "protected: __cdecl pqxx::row::row(class pqxx::result const &,int,int)" (??0row@pqxx@@IEAA@AEBVresult@1@HH@Z) в функции "private: __cdecl pqxx::const_result_iterator::const_result_iterator(class pqxx::result const *,int)" (??0const_result_iterator@pqxx@@AEAA@PEBVresult@1@H@Z).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __cdecl pqxx::transaction_base::commit(void)" (?commit@transaction_base@pqxx@@QEAAXXZ) в функции main.
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class pqxx::result __cdecl pqxx::transaction_base::exec(class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >)" (?exec@transaction_base@pqxx@@QEAA?AVresult@2@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@0@Z) в функции "public: class pqxx::result __cdecl pqxx::transaction_base::exec(class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >)" (?exec@transaction_base@pqxx@@QEAA?AVresult@2@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@Z).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "protected: void __cdecl pqxx::transaction_base::close(void)" (?close@transaction_base@pqxx@@IEAAXXZ) в функции "public: virtual __cdecl pqxx::transaction<0,1>::~transaction<0,1>(void)" (??1?$transaction@$0A@$00@pqxx@@UEAA@XZ).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "protected: virtual void __cdecl pqxx::transaction_base::do_abort(void)" (?do_abort@transaction_base@pqxx@@MEAAXXZ).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "protected: __cdecl pqxx::internal::basic_transaction::basic_transaction(class pqxx::connection &,class pqxx::zview)" (??0basic_transaction@internal@pqxx@@IEAA@AEAVconnection@2@Vzview@2@@Z) в функции "public: __cdecl pqxx::transaction<0,1>::transaction<0,1>(class pqxx::connection &)" (??0?$transaction@$0A@$00@pqxx@@QEAA@AEAVconnection@1@@Z).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "protected: virtual __cdecl pqxx::internal::basic_transaction::~basic_transaction(void)" (??1basic_transaction@internal@pqxx@@MEAA@XZ) в функции "public: virtual __cdecl pqxx::transaction<0,1>::~transaction<0,1>(void)" (??1?$transaction@$0A@$00@pqxx@@UEAA@XZ).
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "private: virtual void __cdecl pqxx::internal::basic_transaction::do_commit(void)" (?do_commit@basic_transaction@internal@pqxx@@EEAAXXZ).
1>C:\Users\sokol\Desktop\c++_projects\еуые\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 17
1>Сборка проекта "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
```

Comment: Использую постоянно библиотеку libpq. Если кратко - то не нужно искать никаких исходников, бери то, что есть в дистрибутиве постгреса. В папке C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\include + C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\lib, а номер версии тот, что установлен. Разрядность проекта на С++ делай соответствующей разрядности постгреса. Никаких проблем ни в C# ни в C++.

Comment: Ingvar , благодарю за совет

Comment: подключение к C# могу показать как. К C++ - сам перехожу на QT, но для сборки использую MS VC, и там и там есть обращение к postgresql так что могу поделиться наработками. Пиши если что